# What is the maximum value of $\frac{x-x^3}{x^4+2x^2+1}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What is the maximum value of $\frac{x-x^3}{x^4+2x^2+1}$  ?

I've got the hint that this problem can be solved by replacing $x$ with tangent $K$.

So it became $\frac{\tan K(1-\tan^2K)}{(\tan^2K+1)^2}=\frac{\tan K}{\tan^2K+1}\cdot\frac{1-\tan^2 K}{\tan^2K+1}=\frac{\sin(2K)}{2(1-\sin^2K)}$
then I have no idea what to do next.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.^^

Comment: Do you mean $\frac{x-x^3}{x^4+2x^2+1}$?

Comment: Your calculation has an error. It should be $\frac 12 \sin 2K \cos 2K$ and the rest is easy.

Comment: The substitution isn't needed. The derivative is 
$$\frac{x^4-6x^2+1}{(x^2+1)^3}$$
Find the zeroes of the top (easy) then check signs.

Comment: @K.defaoite Derivative isn't precalculus, which seems to be the tag specified by OP.

Answer (score 1):

Your method yields the answer. The only thing is that you have assumed $(\frac{1-tan^{2}k}{1+tan^{2}k})$ to be equal to $(sec^{2} x)$ while it is equal to cos 2x

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

With $t=\frac1x - x$
$$\frac{x-x^3}{x^4+2x^2+1}=\frac{\frac1x - x}{x^2+\frac1{x^2}+2}
= \frac{t}{t^2+4}= \frac{\text{sgn}(t)}{(\sqrt{|t|}-\frac2{\sqrt{|t|}})^2+4}\in (-\frac14, \frac14)
$$
Thus, the maximum  is $\frac14$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{x-x^3}{\left(x^2+1\right)^2}$$
substitute $x=\tan k$ and get
$$\frac{\tan k-\tan ^3 k}{\left(1+\tan ^2 k\right)^2}=\frac{\tan k}{1+\tan^2 k} \cdot \frac{1-\tan^2 k}{1+\tan^2 k}=\frac{1}{2}\sin 2k\cos 2k=\frac{1}{4}\sin 4k $$
as $\sin 4k$ has a maximum of $1$, the expression has a maximum of $\frac{1}{4}$.

Answer (score 0):

Another way$$\frac{x-x^3}{{(x^2+1)}^2}-\frac{1}{4}=-\left(\frac{x^4+2x^2+1-4x+4x^3}{{(x^2+1)}^2}\right)=-\left(\frac{{(x^2+2x-1)}^2}{{(x^2+1)}^2}\right)\le 0$$